# how to delete multiple ids in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, delete-row

my table name is `paids` and i want to delete all the ids which have same `ot_id` here is my `databsae`

i have data like this

```
 |id|  |ot_id|
   1      20
   2      20
   3      20
   4      20
   5      20
   6      20
```

```php
public function deleteOT($id)
{
    $deleteid = Paid::where();
    return Common::Message("Order Taker", 3);
}
```

here i want to delete how i can do that in laravel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should spend some time reading Laravel docs, which are very good source for learning the basics.

```php
public function deleteOt($id)
{
    Paid::where('ot_id', $id)->delete();

    return Common::Message("Order Taker", 3);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To select multiple rows at once you can use, `whereIn()`

```
public function deleteOt($id)
{
   Paid::whereIn('id', $ids)->delete();
   return Common::Message("Order Taker", 3);
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

```
1. $id => it should be an array when you delete multiple ids.

     public function deleteOt($id) {
           Paid::whereIn('id', $ids)->delete();
           return Common::Message("Order Taker", 3);
     }
```